# Year to Date Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet with four diffrent sheets: Total, January, February and March. Each sheet has sales for product A and B.

[image]

In total sheet I have a list with the three months and when I select a specific month, the values changes in cells B6 and C6, which is good. The following formula is locatated at those cells: =INDIRECT("'"&$C$2&"'!"&"B3") and =INDIRECT("'"&$C$2&"'!"&"C3")

Now, I need to know a year to date value depending on selected month. For example, I have 10 sales in January for product A and 12 sales in February for the same product. If I select in total sheet February month, what formula can I use to have 22 sells?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it.

In cell B7, enter this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(J2:INDEX(J:J,MATCH(C2,J:J,))&"!b3"),"<>0"))
```

In cell C7, enter this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(J2:INDEX(J:J,MATCH(C2,J:J,))&"!c3"),"<>0"))
```

Comment: ExcelHero good formula. @Sebastian, just be aware that these formulas are adding a range of Sheets, i.e March YTD is the sum of Jan to Mar Sheets, therefore if let's say the user copy or add any Sheet between Jan and March the values in that Sheet for the corresponding cells will also be added. To test just copy Jan Sheet after Feb and see results for March. Just something to be aware of and advice users about it.

Comment: That is very usefull. What happend if I need to do a querter to date? For Example I have April month and I must to evaluate from January to March, when I select April the sum start over for the next three months?. THX!

Comment: That's a little bit more tricky, but it would involve offsetting this: `J2:INDEX(J:J,MATCH(C2,J:J,))` to return the proper three months for the quarter. It's a substantial enhancement though. Please consider writing up a new question.